# Getting value of two way binds pre render

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible in AngularJS to get the value of all {{thisValueHere}} before the DOM is rendered? For example, could I find all the {{}} a user has added to a directive and use that information to generate the template? I understand that an API could be exposed on my directives for this purpose, I'm simple curious if this can be done.

Comment: The DOM is always rendered first, but you could use `ng-bind-template` to provide a default value without the app showing a blank `{{}}` when the page renders

Comment: Which part of 'DOM' is that? Is it your directive's nested DOM? How do you plan to get these values? The context of the question is missing.

Comment: Within my custom directive, a user can supply {{boundVariables}}. Can I access those boundVariables before rendering the template?